# Is there any selenium specific testing framework available?

Tags: java, selenium, frameworks, qaf

Is there any readymade utilities/framework available which can provide some common functionalities for automation needs like data management, reporting etc. Java is most preferable language.

Answer (score 0):

[TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) provides an extensible framework for automation management. It integrates with popular IDEs such as Eclipse, and provides the ability to write data-driven tests, parallel execution (using Selenium Grid), and a host of [other features](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).
For reporting needs, [ReportNG](http://reportng.uncommons.org/) is a plug-in for TestNG, that provides neat HTML reports.

Comment: yes we can utilize testng but still we have to write some selenium specific utilities to use in automation so i am in search of some ready to use framework specific to selenium no matters it uses junit or testng

Comment: I have used qaf and it is useful for managing driver instances for parallel executions and it has very good concepts of custom component, page hierarchy, object repository, listeners and best part is Reporting.

Answer (score 0):

[Windmill](http://www.getwindmill.com/) is a Selenium type of testing framework for testing web pages. It works with all languages as you program it for web. You can record what you want to test, and it will perform it for you. Very nice!

[Here is a nice video (popup)](http://www.getwindmill.com/features/windmill-introduction-video#podPressPlayerSpace_1)